# In Vim tab-completion of file names doesn't work

Tags: vim, autocomplete

When I try to open a file in Vim (Linux) for editing, when I press TAB, Vim autocompletes filename only with filenames from the current directory. However, having searched on the Web, I suppose that from version 7 Vim should support bash-like filename autocompletion using filenames from all the directories in the search path.

Say, there is a file `file1` in a directory `dir1` (which directory is also in the environment variable PATH).

I type the following commands in Vim:

```
set path=/dir1
set wildmode=list:longest
```

And then, when I type:

```
:e fil<TAB>
```

The filename is not autocompleted. How to enable this feature in Vim?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tab-completion works. You just expect it to do something it is not actually supposed to do.

`:e[dit]` and its siblings (`:sp[lit]`, `:vs[plit]`, `:tabe[dit]`) don't use the `path` option at all, no matter what version of Vim you have.

- Use `:fin[d] fil<Tab>` instead (and `:sf[ind]`, `:vert sf[ind]`, `:tabf[ind]`).
- Use `set path=/dir1/**` to make `:find` recursive.

See `:help 'path'` and `:help :find`.

**edit**

It is generally considered "good practice" to start Vim from the root of your project:

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ vim somefile
```

The main advantage being that it sets Vim's "current directory" to a usable value that allows you to browse your project relatively easily or use external programs on your project in a clean and intuitive way.

Comment: I like adding each file's directory to my path as I edit, adding it to the BEGINNING of the path for faster searches for related files. I do the same thing for tags files; I thought I created a wiki page about it but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @Ben, if you don't find that wiki page, could you elaborate a bit on your workflow?

Comment: Apparently I never made it a real page: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/User:Fritzophrenic/Fast_find

On every BufRead, I will remove the default path from the path, remove the current file's path from the path, prepend the default path, and then prepend the current file's path. Thus future searches prefer files in the same directory as the current file. I do the same thing for tags files for similar reasons.